# How Can we update variable or text in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, azure-analysis-services, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I am trying to update variable or text in Power App canvas using same Power app.

When user click on Power App button it should show state of azure analysis service either Running or Paused state in Power App itself, want to show state of service in same screen.

I have a power app canvas which is having Button and calling flows by clicking Power App button.

Flow will call some API and get some data stored in JSON and finally storing required value in some variable.

So I want to update that same value back to Power App canvas where I have text field.

Please help how can I achieve this ?

Below is Power App Canvas:

[image]

Below is flow calling in Power App Button:

[image]

So How Can I update the values which are coming from http --> Json --> Variable value into Power App Text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user set or updatecontext operation to return data from your flow

Take a look at this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april18/microsoft-flow/return-data-powerapps)

[Additional article for help](https://d365demystified.com/2021/04/29/call-a-flow-from-canvas-power-app-and-get-back-response-power-platform/)

Answer (score 1):

In your flow, use the PowerApp V2 connector with the 'Respond to a PowerApp or flow' action and define an output (variable) that will expose the return value to the calling PowerApp.